# How to get the count of undoable operation of a wpf richtextbox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, undo

how can i track the number of undo operation of a wpf richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Undo logic is private inside `TextBoxBase` class and it depends on internal `UndoManager` class. I advise you not to hack with Reflection, because your code can break if MS decides to change implementation, but if you decide to do it anyway, you can use Reflector to get code of `TextBoxBase.CanUndo` property to understand how it works. Number of available undo operations is probably in the `UndoManager.UndoCount` property, but there's additional logic you need to consider.